# Is it unsafe to insert data from ajax requests to the database in web2py

Tags: web2py

Is it possible to insert malicious code via ajax requests from input fields to the database if the data is not form-processed?

The DAL connection is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inserting data from Ajax requests should be no more or less safe than via non-Ajax requests. Form processing doesn't protect against SQL injection. However, the web2py DAL does protect against SQL injection, so as long as you are using the DAL to handle the inserts, you should be fine.